# A martingale sequence?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $a_{1n},..., a_{nn}$ be non-random constants satisfying $\sup_{i,n} |a_{in}| \le C$, with $C$ non depending on $i,n$, and $X_1,...,X_n$ a sequence of i.i.d. random variables such that $E|X_1|^p < \infty$ for some $1 \le p < 2$ and $E(X_i) = 0$, $\forall i$. The sequence $M_n = a_{1n}X_1 + ... + a_{nn}X_n$ is a martingale? Many thanks.

Comment: What's your filtration? What have you tried?

Comment: Why the double index on a ? Because depends all the constants depends on $n$. The filtration will be $\sigma = (X_1,...,X_n)$. I forgot to say that the constants $a_{in}$ satisfies $|a_{in}| \le C$ with $C$ non depending on $n$ and $i$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathcal F_n=\sigma(X_k;k\leqslant n)$, then $\mathbb E(M_{n+1}\mid \mathcal F_n)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_{k,n+1}X_k$, which, except when $a_{k,n}$ does not depend on $n$, is not $M_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_{k,n}X_k$.

Comment: Ok! And if $X_1,X_2,...$ is a sequence of non-negative random variables and $a_{1n},...,a_{nn}$ non-negative and non-random constants, there is a chance that $M_n = a_{1n}X_1 + ... + a_{nn}X_n$ be a submartingale with respect to a filtration $\sigma(X_1,...,X_n)$? Thank you.

Comment: Look, since I wrote down explicitely $\mathbb E(M_{n+1}\mid\mathcal F_n)$, you can check this yourself, no?